# Logout in case of a bad request

Tags: admin-on-rest

thanks for the amazing job you've done with AOR, this have been a great source of inspiration for me, especially in how to implement a proper redux store.

My question : 
If I make a bad request, (code 400), AOR log me out of the app. 
How can I prevent this and instead show a notification to my user ?

Answer (score 1):

You can follow the [instructions](https://github.com/marmelab/admin-on-rest/blob/master/docs/Authentication.md) to achieve it:

```
import { AUTH_ERROR } from 'admin-on-rest';

export default (type, params) => {
    if (type === AUTH_ERROR) {
        // As I noticed, this code is executed for any error, not only for auth-one.
        // So process the error as you wish (show message), don't log out.
    }
    // Then resolve the promise.
    return Promise.resolve();
};
```